How to scale down the entire UI content to fit in a preview area in Jetpack Compose?
I'm implementing a theme chooser screen for my app. The idea is to provide various themes that the user can choose from and show previews of two screens so that the user can see how the theme will look after selecting it.
I display this home screen as a preview:

This is how my theme chooser screen looks:

I want to scale down the content of the home screen to display the entire home screen content within the available area of the theme chooser preview.
I've tried using Modifier.scale(0.4f) and Modifier.graphicsLayer(scaleX = 0.4f, scaleY = 0.4f), but this only scales down what's already visible.

One idea that seems to work is using a local provider to provide a scale factor to the Compose UI like this:
val LocalScaleFactor = compositionLocalOf { 1f }

@Composable
fun ScaleFactorProvider(
    scaleFactor: Float = 1f,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalScaleFactor provides scaleFactor,
        content = content
    )
}

val Int.scaleDp: Dp
    @Composable
    get() = (this * localScaleFactor).dp

val Int.scaleSp: TextUnit
    @Composable
    get() = (this * localScaleFactor).sp

val localScaleFactor: Float
    @Composable get() = LocalScaleFactor.current

ScaleFactorProvider(0.4f) {
   HomeScreenPreview()
}

While this method works, it requires extensive code changes. I have to use scaleDp and scaleSP everywhere, and for some views like Icon, which I don't usually provide any size and just use the default size, I now have to define the size. This is quite inconvenient.
Is there an alternative way to scale down the dimensions of the entire UI tree to fit the available parent size in Jetpack Compose?
Edit 1:
I've tried what @Leviathan suggested in the comment. It works but it makes it hard to make the UI responsible. My current UI looks something like this

Column

Row

Box 1f weight
Box 1f weight


Rest of the UI



Now I have to move the content of the row outside

Box

Column

Empty Box 1f weight


Rest of the UI
Box left preview
Box right preview



After scaling down, both previews will be at the centre and I have to provide x and y offsets to place where I want them to be.
The issue with this method is that since the preview box is bound to the parent, the alignments could be off based on the user device dimension.

What happens when you draw the preview in its full size taking up the entire screen and then scale it down?

take a look at BoxWithConstraints layout same as box with the ability to set min and max witdth and height: https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/foundation/layout/boxwithconstraints/

@Leviathan Just tried this solution. It works but it makes it hard to make the UI responsible.
My current UI looks something like this

Column
Row
Box 1f weight
Box 1f weight
Rest of the UI

Now I have to move the content of the row outside

Box
Column
Empty Box 1f weight
Rest of the UI
Box left preview
Box right preview

After scaling down, both previews will be at the centre and I have to provide x and y offsets to place where I want them to be. When I test this on multiple screen sizes, alignments are a bit off based on the device.

Try providing a custom Density to your composable.
Density implementation:
private data class MyDensity(override val density: Float, override val fontScale: Float) : Density

Composable:
val scale = 0.4f
val curDensity = LocalDensity.current
val myDensity = MyDensity(curDensity.density * scale, curDensity.fontScale)
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalDensity provides myDensity) {
    //Content
}

Edit:
An example:
private data class MyDensity(override val density: Float, override val fontScale: Float) : Density

@Composable
fun ScalableScreen() {
    var scale by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(1f) }
    fun doScale(value: Float) {
        scale *= value
    }
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {
        Row {
            Button(onClick = { doScale(0.9f) }) { Text("-") }
            Button(onClick = { doScale(1.1f) }) { Text("+") }
        }
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(scale),
        ) {
            val curDensity = LocalDensity.current
            val myDensity = MyDensity(curDensity.density * scale, curDensity.fontScale)
            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalDensity provides myDensity) {
                Content(Color.DarkGray, Color.LightGray)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun Content(color1: Color, color2: Color, ) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.background(color1).padding(8.dp)
    ) {
        Row {
            repeat(2) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.height(100.dp).weight(1f).padding(8.dp).background(color2)
                ) {
                    Button(onClick = {}) { Text(text = "Button $it") }
                }
            }
        }
        Text(
            text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. ".repeat(20),
            modifier = Modifier.background(color2)
        )
    }
}

Screen recording:


This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Extremely clever, thank you. But is there a direct way to scale images as well?  Vector graphics scale nicely, but I'm having trouble with bitmapped images.

Does this image have any size modifiers? If not, is it possible to set its size? I think it happens because Image will take size depending on painter.intrinsicSize (i.e. bitmap dimensions) as long as it fits into constraints. E.g. 100x100 Image will keep the same size in 1000x1000 Box or 200x200 Box. @SMBiggs
